# translate from oracle to db2

Tags: oracle, db2

If time permits, would someone please let me know what syntax would need to be changed to accommodate this from oracle to db2? I am hoping to use the db2 command line prompt DB2 client version 10.5.3. Please let me know if you need anymore information.  I changed the VARCHAR2 to VARCHAR and the NUMBER(3) to INT as well as NUMBER(10 to INT.  Its much appreciated. Jean T.

```
DECLARE
   v_count   PLS_INTEGER := 0;

   TYPE inv_rt IS RECORD (upc         VARCHAR(20),
                          store       INT,
                          inv_avail   INT
                         );

   TYPE inv_tt IS TABLE OF inv_rt;
   inv_arr          inv_tt;


   CURSOR cur_data (in_date  DATE)
   IS
      SELECT i.upc, i.storenumber, i.inv_avail - SUM(t.unitvolume) AS inv_avail 
        FROM zz_tran      t,
             zz_start_inv i
       WHERE t.weekenddate <= in_date
         AND t.upc = i.upc
         AND t.storenumber = i.storenumber
       GROUP BY i.upc, i.storenumber, i.inv_avail;

BEGIN

   inv_arr := inv_tt();

   FOR d IN (SELECT DISTINCT weekenddate 
               FROM zz_tran 
              ORDER BY weekenddate
            )
   LOOP

      inv_arr := inv_tt();

      OPEN  cur_data (d.weekenddate);
      FETCH cur_data BULK COLLECT INTO inv_arr;
      CLOSE cur_data;

      FORALL i IN inv_arr.FIRST .. inv_arr.LAST
         UPDATE zz_tran
            SET inv_avail = inv_arr(i).inv_avail
          WHERE weekenddate = d.weekenddate
            AND upc = inv_arr(i).upc
            AND storenumber = inv_arr(i).store;

      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: I think you would need a common table expression that unions back on itself.  I can just barely type one in to parse words so I'm not going to be much help.  But maybe this helps someone else answer.

Comment: NUMBER(10) is not equivalent to INT. INT's max value is 2,147,483,647, while NUMBER(10)'s max value is 9,999,999,999. You should probably use DECIMAL(10).

Answer (score 1):

If converting from Oracle to Db2, you can create your Db2 database in Oracle Compatibility mode. That will allow Db2 to recognize e.g. `VARCHAR2` natively.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/c_compat_oracle.html

You can also use the Database Conversion Workbench to assist in converting from Oracle to Db2

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=05901c97-75b2-47a1-9c32-25f748855913